# How to install mathtools in Texworks

Tags: installing, mathtools

I would like to install mathtools in Texworks on windows 7. How can I do this task?

Comment: You can't. texworks is an editor, not a tex system. Which tex system are you using?

Comment: I am using MikTex 2.9.

Comment: Then use the miktex package manager.

Comment: See also [Working With the Package Manager from the MikTeX documentation](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/pkgmgt.html).

Comment: I am trying to install mh package with MikTex Package Manager in windows. When I tried to install it, I got this error:

Unknown archive file size.

Comment: You can't install it: this package doesn't exist anymore. `mh` was split last year into two packages with distinct maintainers, `mathtools`  and `breqn`. Your MPM seems rather old, and should be `synchronised` first. Then you'll see the two new packages, and will be able ton install it from MPM.